# Vue.js: Share the component by "Moving" it around instead of copying it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a comment system which has a lot of the comments (*like 300+*) with Vue.js.

And **there's a admin section for each of the comment** (marked as `Component` below), the admin section will appear when the cursor stay on the comment.

So if there're 300 comments, the admin section component will be copied like 300 times, which is not good for mobile even on the computer (cause **too many components**).

[image]

What I'm thinking is: Is it possible to **share the same component** by **moving** it around the comments so there will be only one admin section like this?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `v-if` directive (as opposed to `v-show`). It should usually do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any technique that lets you move the common component to any place within the page. This is usually done in the jQuery world, but it results in a very messy and hard-to-debug code.

As mentioned by @Nils in comments, you can use `v-if`, which does not render the floating component in the DOM. Therefore, it will not increase the weight of the page, and your page will feel fast (relatively).

Technically it should not make any difference as Vue.js is comfortable in rendering 1000s of rows. Ref: http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=316 (click on the colorful table to see some interesting stats)

In the working example below, the "Do something" button comes into DOM only after you place the cursor inside one of the comment fields. Till then, it is not rendered into DOM.

```js
Vue.component('comment-block', {
    props: ["comment"],
    template: `
        <div class="comment" @mouseenter="displayOptions=true" @mouseleave="displayOptions=false">
            <div class="author">{{comment.author}} wrote:</div>
            <input type='text' v-model='comment.message'/>
            <div class="options" v-if="displayOptions"><button>Do something</button></div>
        </div>`,
    data: function(){
        return {
            displayOptions: false
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        comments: [
          {id: 0, author: 'Bob', message: "This is my comment #1"},
          {id: 1, author: 'Frank', message: "Comment #2"},
          {id: 2, author: 'Joe', message: "One more comment in this page (#3)"}
        ]
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.comment {
    padding: 5px;
}
.comment .author {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
}
.comment input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
}
.comment .options {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.5/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>List of comments:</p>
        <comment-block :comment="comment" v-for="comment in comments"></comment-block>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** the "Do something" button does nothing yet, other than simply showing up, for this example.

This is one way to keep the interface light, but as mentioned in the performance analysis blog post above, this micro-optimization really does not matter, unless you run into some issues.